# Which repository contains the official and working JDBC Postgis drivers?

Tags: maven, sbt, dependency-management

If I look in the [Maven repositories](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22net.postgis%22%20AND%20a%3A%22postgis-jdbc-java2d%22), I can find:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.postgis</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgis-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

If I try to use it (with SBT), then this error is raised:

```
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.postgis#postgis-jdbc;2.1.0SVN: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

Here I can find its source code:
https://github.com/postgis/postgis-java/tree/v2.2.0

*UPDATE*:

If I clear the Maven cache, the above problem appears.

Comment: Can't you just use the normal Postgres JDBC driver?

Comment: Postgis driver is a wrapper to the normal JDBC driver and adds special Postgis capabilities for working with geometric columns.

Comment: You're depending on `2.1.0` but it should be `2.2.0`.

Comment: I just tried it with **real** maven and it works fine. Its an **sbt** issue. It has nothing to do with postgis or postgres.

Comment: @david.perez It looks like a transitive dependency issue. I would look how you can lock/force dependencies with sbt: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Library-Management.html or figure out what is depending that incorrect version.

Comment: it looks like a SBT related bug.  It's the 1st time it is unable to download a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Mystery solved:

It is a SBT misconfiguration.

I had the old postgis dependency `"org.postgis" % "postgis-jdbc" % "2.1.0SVN" exclude("postgres", "postgres")` in `project/build.sbt`.  I loooked only in `./build.sbt`.

This dependency has disappeared from the Maven repositories.
Only computers with this dependency cached, didn't have this problem.